# How do I assign an incrementing user ID to new users in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: java, servlets

i've just started to learn Java, and I've a problem with creating a Java server.

On HTML, there should be a form, and JavaScript witch submits that form every second (By POST method). The form should have a hidden field, with the value of user ID. Server should look for a user id in the request. It should give new ID to the new users, and to the visited users, show their id.

After each form submit, the inscription changes to: null, 2, null, 2, null, 2.... here is the code:

```
public class ServerConnect extends AbstractHandler{
         private AtomicInteger ids = new AtomicInteger(0);    
         private String userId;

         public void handle(String target,
         Request baseRequest,
         HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response)    throws IOException, ServletException
         {

             response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
             response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
             baseRequest.setHandled(true);
             response.getWriter().println(PageGenerator.generateForm(userId));
             userId = request.getParameter("userId");

             if (userId == null){
                 ids.getAndIncrement();
                 userId = ids.toString();
             }        
          }

         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

               Server server = new Server(8080);
               server.setHandler(new ServerConnect());
               server.start();
               server.join();
        }
}

public class PageGenerator {

    public static String generateForm(String val){
        String htmlCode = null;

        htmlCode = "...
             <script>
                function reload(){ 
                   document.forms['MainForm'].submit();
                }
                setTimeout("reload()", 1000); 
             </script>    
             .... + val + ...
             <form id='MainForm' method = 'POST'>
                 <input type = "hidden" name = "userId" value = \""+ val + \""> 
             <form>
                             ...       
    return htmlCode;
    }    

}
```

I can't get why is user ID equals to 2, and why after user gets his id, it's value changes to null, and then, to 2 again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are rendering your page before the userId has been resolved. You have `PageGenerator.generateForm(userId)` before you check `if(userId == null)`

Also, you should understand that `AtomicLong.getAndIncrement()` is a compound operation, similar to `i++` (but is a single atomic operation).

So you need to have code like the following:

```
if (userId == null){
     userId = ids.getAndIncrement();
}
```

Finally, I'm not certain about the lifecycle of the `AbstractHandler` but it would be reasonable to assume that a new instance of your class is being instantiated by Jetty every other request.  As `ids` is scoped as a "instance" field, it is discarded (and thus effectively reset) with new requests.

**Edit** answers on Jetty's threading model here: [Jetty Architecture](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Architecture)

To fix this, you would need to declare `ids` as `static final` (and thus effectively make it a "Singleton" ID generator) to have it survive multiple requests. An ok approach for a toy application, but not something you'd necessarily do in production code.